# Gift first push isn't reflecting when i try to clone the repo

Tags: git, react-native

Please could you explain this to me?
I already have a react native project I'm working on on Android. But I want to port it to ios. So I got a mac pc

So now I want to clone the app to my mac without copying it manually.
Here is what I did:

1. Created a git repo
2. Came to my HP where I have the project
3. Added the repo with:

   - Git init
   - Git add remote origin (repo-link)
   - Git add .
   - Git commit -m "Initial commit"
   - Git push origin master

Now I go to my mac. And do this from terminal

1. Git clone (repo-link)

But when it's done. I only get READ.md

I don't get the full project.

Comment: Try verifying you are cloning from the master branch in your mac and the master branch is updated correctly in your online repo.

Comment: Please how do i make such verification ?

Comment: You could use this git command: git clone --single-branch --branch master <remote-repo> and go to your github or git host repository to see if all the files are correctly placed in the master branch

Comment: @JasonParra: I wouldn't recommend using `--single-branch` to anyone who's a Git beginner - it leaves too many traps for later. Instead, the OP might want to use `git branch -a` to look to see what remote-tracking names they have in each clone.

Comment: Actually I just ran that code without the single branch git clone --branch master <remote-repo> and it seems to have grabbed the files. I don't understand it. when i clone other developer's repo, I never use to specify branch, why is this different ?

Comment: I assume repo-link might be something like a git hosting environment, for instance GitHub. If that is the case, log onto it and check the history commit in your browser. If not, then where is your remote? Something like GitHub, a shared folder in your network, something else?

Comment: BTW: on your HP it appears you have created an empty repository, probably put README in it, add all (.) then push. No wonder you get only that on the Mac. This is what I understand from the information you are providing. Try to expand on this if I'm mistaken.

Comment: i don't put only read me, I use git add . and I only got the files when i cloned from the master branch